# Is there a reason why I should refrain from specifying where I work in my class discussions?

Tags: professionalism, privacy

I recently started taking a class. There is a "get to know you" discussion forum that we are all supposed to participate in. Is there a good reason I should refrain from mentioning my specific place of employment?

Comment: What would you gain by not telling them that? Or .. what would you gain by telling them?

Comment: @GrayCygnus that's what I don't understand. Many people mention where they work, but I don't know the significance of doing it. What are the reasons for wanting to vs not wanting to?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I guess my concern is if it could somehow hurt me by doing it. Maybe a fellow student doesn't like my responses or ends up disagreeing with me and chooses to cause harm to my career somehow out of spite (I don't plan on this being an issue but you never know who you will have to deal with).

Comment: I see no harm in telling other what is your work. Unless you are some sort of secret agent or work in confidential matters.

Comment: you need a "why" to make this question answerable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a workplace issue, just like telling your friends or family where you work isn't a workplace issue, and it will mostly just come down to opinion - you are far more likely to know how likely you are to say something so controversial or detestable that someone would choose to try to ruin your career over it.

Comment: I think this would be a good candidate for migration to [IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com), since you're asking about interactions in a non-workplace setting.

Comment: Your real name is probably more than enough information for a dedicated person to figure out where you work.

Answer (score 4):

There is pretty much no downside to telling people where you work. You are not revealing any confidential secrets, and it's extremely unlikely that anyone can use the information against you.

Exceptions might be if you are deeply embarrassed about where you work ("yourbestporno.com") or you work for a secret intelligence agency (not out of the question - I knew several people who worked for [GCHQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_Communications_Headquarters) and [AWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Weapons_Establishment) and they tended to introduce themselves as 'working for a government laboratory'). Conceivably if you worked for a stealth mode startup where your interests might give away the company's program.

Comment: yourbestporno.com is not a real website. Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: If you do work for a sensitive TLA you normally have a cover job that you can tell F&F that  you work for.

Comment: @Neuromancer No, it actually doesn't work like that in my experience.